# Conversion of float to ndarray or viceversa

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am tying to calculate mean absolute error, but when I execute the following print statement

```
print('MAE:  %5.2f kcal/mol'%np.abs(output - TZ).mean(axis=0))
```

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Additional Info:

```
output = 

[-0.01200975 -0.01200975 -0.01200975 ..., -0.01042357 -0.01200975
 -0.01042357]

TZ =

[[ 2.43307638]
 [ 1.981444  ]
 [ 0.25338271]
 ..., 
 [-0.18407178]
 [-0.734635  ]
 [ 1.724509  ]]
```

I am new to python, can anyone tell me how to convert TZ into float or vice versa ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out the answer.

I reshaped the output as output.reshape(output.shape[0],1) now both the variables are in same format.